# Uploading and processing file with progress bar in asp.net with jquery, mvc3 and html5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, upload, progress-bar

I see there are quite a few upload /progressbar components, most of which use swf/flash.

I am implementing a feature in an app that entails uploading a smallish file (< 1 Mb) and then loading it into a database (longish operation - 10 -15 minutes, dont ask :/ ).

I'd like to show progress information for both phases of the import process.  What would be your recommended strategy for implementing this feature? Any tools I should consider?

Clients are using mostly IE8, but I'd like to avoid using Flash if possible.

Comment: You can go with Ajax based solution..

Comment: That is an option, but I was hoping someone had implemented some/most of this functionality, so that I did not have to write it all from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You said HTML5, then you mentioned IE8. On IE8 you will have to use jquery [uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) but if you have modern browser then you can use HTML5 (see [tutorial](http://www.alexanderschnitzler.de/2011/06/howto-build-an-html5-file-uploader-with-ajax/))

Comment: Uploading the file and showing a progress bar isnt that difficult.  What I am looking for is a method that will show a progress bar for the combined process of uploading the file itself, and then the processing and storing the file content in the database, preferably with helpful status messages along the way.

Comment: The second link is broken

Answer (score 0):

You have to use model box, pls see following link...
http://www.queness.com/resources/html/modal/jquery-modal-window.html
when uploading a file call,this modelbox function,after uploading close automatically by calling this , $.modal.close()  function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5 file reader then the file progress is easy to catch. Read the article of HTML5 field reader API on HTML5 rocks to get the further info about file reader API.

[Filr Reader API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)